# GWT GUI design methods

Tags: gwt, user-interface

I am trying to develop a GWT GUI that with the help of PhoneGap will run on a mobile device.  Simple multiview app with different buttons / text boxes on each view. Each view can only be navigated to from a single predetermined view.  ie my Views might flow something like ViewA - ViewB - View C - Back to ViewB - ViewA.
Each view will have a back button ( Not the browser button as this is of no use in a mobile phone gap app )
Is there any example / book out there that would cover something like this. I have looked at the Activities and Places framework but this looks like overkill for what I want.

Comment: check out this: http://mobilegwt.appspot.com/showcase/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to support the browser back button or browser bookmarks, you could implement basic navigation by adding one view at a time to a parent container. You can find an example of this [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-web-toolkit/5NRxedORK-k).

Answer (score 0):

### Activities and Places framework

deliver value over large projects ( more than 5-10 screens ) https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces

Do not ignore it on an initial attempt. The learning curve is steep but it delivers

1) Code segregation with clear modularity to allow unit testing.

2) Performance optimization with code splitting and fragment merging.

3) Automatic history tracking

### GWT History Manager

You can still use GWT History Manager without use of "Places". https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory

Also good starting point would be to look for other gwt phone gap like

https://github.com/dennisjzh/GwtMobile-PhoneGap

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gwtmobile.phonegap